WebSocket Starting services issue not starting websocket
public async void StartServer()
{
    try
    {
        httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://102.172.45.123:1222/");
        httpListener.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error in connection: " + ex.Message);

    }
}

ExeptionCaught:

System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'


1)Change the port
Maybe previously you have launched the app and then you have closed but the process is not killed or closed so the using port is not released.
I recommend you to close the socket on closing app.
For example if you are in windows form app use
 protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
  {
      StopSocket();
      base.OnClosed(e);
  }

This will stop the socket and release the used port.
2)Another thing is that, As far as I know server will be served on 127.0.0.1
